# How to set options value with object in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have:

```
 <select name="test" id="test" class="" 
  data-bind="
  options: myArray, 
  value: idSelected,
  optionsText: 'name',
  optionsValue: 'id',
 optionsCaption: 'All'">
```

I dont want only id, i want set in object a id and name of my array when you select an item from the list. Sample:

I want this result:

```
  idSelected = {id:1, name:'Test'};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `optionsValue` from your bindings. This will set the `idSelected` to be the objects of `observableArray` rather than a string ([documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#example-3-drop-down-list-representing-arbitrary-javascript-objects-not-just-strings))

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.myArray = ko.observableArray([{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Test 2'
  }]);

  self.idSelected = ko.observable();

  self.idSelected.subscribe((selected) => {
    console.log(self.idSelected());
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select name="test" id="test" class="" data-bind="
  options: myArray, 
  value: idSelected,
  optionsText: 'name',
 optionsCaption: 'All'">
```